# Cant center my Widgets in Container using Column() flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, containers, center, flutter-column

On this pic is my
[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCEuZ.png)

And when I use Column(), my design isn't a center :( Watch it -> [step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMJDo.png)

also I cant press on it when I wrapped in Column() and I dont see any mistakes:

```
 Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      color: colorMars,
                    ),
                    height: 200,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            icon: const FaIcon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                              size: 80,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              colorMars = active;
                              if (colorMars == active) {
                                colorVenus = inActive;
                              } else {
                                colorMars = inActive;
                              }

                              setState(() {});
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

PS For icons I use this package [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)
In pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
```

Full of code here -> [full_code](https://flutlab.io/editor/401ff708-b7f0-4942-9550-0c48d07793f6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `iconSize: 80` in your `IconButton`. And full code will be

```
 Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      color: colorMars,
                    ),
                    height: 200,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            iconSize: 80,
                            icon: const FaIcon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              colorMars = active;
                              if (colorMars == active) {
                                colorVenus = inActive;
                              } else {
                                colorMars = inActive;
                              }

                              setState(() {});
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Based on the `IconButton` [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html)

> When creating an icon button with an Icon, do not override the icon's
> size with its Icon.size parameter, use the icon button's iconSize
> parameter instead. For example do this:
>
> `IconButton(iconSize: 72, icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), ...)`
>
> Avoid doing this:
>
> `IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 72), ...)`
>
> If you do, the button's size will be based on the default icon size,
> not 72, which may produce unexpected layouts and clipping issues.

If you override `FaIcon` with size 80 without adding `IconButton` size, the `FaIcon` will be bigger than its parent (`IconButton`) and you get unexpected layout.